# How does Flask keep the request global threadsafe

Tags: python, flask, global

In flask every function has access to a *request* global. How do the designers of flask stop that global from being overwritten in the middle of one request when another one starts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a threadlocal, not a true global. Since each thread can only be dealing with one request at a time, there's no danger of interference.

In fact there's a full description of exactly this in the Flask docs [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#accessing-request-data).

(Still doesn't necessarily make it a good design, of course.)

Comment: That's very cool. Thanks for the link too. Is it possible/adviseable to bind your own information in that way?

Comment: For a 'bad design' it works really very well, though. I admire the architecture, FWIW.